# How to unzip gzipped response body in Cypress

Tags: node.js, cypress

I have a response body returned gzipped and I am trying to [ZLib](https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js) library to unzip gzipped response in Cypress but getting a compile error. How to use this gzip library correctly in cypress?

The error I am getting is:

[image]

**test.js**

```
require('zlib')

cy.request({url: fileUrl})
  .then((resp) => {
       var gzip = new Zlib.Gunzip()
       gzip.decompress(resp.body)
});
```

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "zlib": "^1.0.5"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently trying to execute this code in the browser, which will not work. If you want to run some code in backend you should use cypress tasks, check documentation [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task), also if you are confused look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680757/in-cypress-when-to-use-custom-command-vs-task)